# How to make product greyout when backorder product is not in stock?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, product, orders

I have this function for WooCommerce that makes products greyed out and non selectable if products are not currently in stock.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 
'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But this function only works when product is variable without backorder available. When Backorder is enabled, this function don't works.

How to make this function to function also for backorder products?

I writen this function, but it's not working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 
function grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder( $grey_out, $variation ) {

    if (  ! $variation->is_in_stock() && $variation->backorders_require_notification() ){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Test URL](https://www.muaythaimall.com/shop/fairtex-boxing-gloves-f-day-limited-edition-bgv11/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forget some things in your code. Try this *(tested and works)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder', 10, 2 );
function grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder( $grey_out, $variation ) {

    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() && $variation->backorders_require_notification() )
        $grey_out = false;

    return $grey_out;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

*(Works on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+)*

> This code will work if you set your concerned variations this way:
>
> [image]